# ng-change doesn't get fired for email input unless I enter a valid email address

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-change, angularjs-watch

Model value for invalid email input is always undefined. I would like to be able to check if the user has entered any text (even if it's not yet a valid email address).

Please check plnkr for more details on the implementation: http://plnkr.co/edit/qV2eqGFhPvZSZKexDVF2?p=preview

Html:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form>
      <div>
        <label for="email">Email address</label>
            <input ng-keyup="keyUp()" ng-change="changed()" type="email" name="email" id="email" ng-model='user.email'/>
        </div>
    </form>
  </body>
```

Controller:

```
    var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.user = {};
  $scope.$watch('user.email', function (val){
      console.log("Watch: "+$scope.user.email);
    });
    $scope.changed = function(){
      console.log("Changed: "+$scope.user.email);
    }
    $scope.keyUp = function(){
      console.log("KeyUp: "+$scope.user.email);
    }
});
```

Cheers.

Comment: This is by design since the input type is "email". Why do you want to check for non-valid emails?

Comment: using $parser or $formatter inside your own directive would give you the value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could get the value of the input element on keyup

```
$scope.keyUp = function(){
   console.log('value: ', event.target.value)
}
```

Comment: You are corrent! Thanks for providing an example.

Comment: This is answer is flawed for several reasons. First, you are relying on a global variable and making the controller less testable - there is a reason why DI is so deeply rooted in Angular. Second, you are completely bypassing `ng-model`, which could be attached to a non-text-input, thus tightly coupling the controller and the view.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a way. You can use $ViewValue.

Add a ng-form to the form

```
body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form name="myForm" ng-form="myForm">
      <div>
        <label for="email">Email address</label>
            <input ng-keyup="keyUp()" ng-change="changed()" type="email" name="email" id="email" ng-model='user.email'/>
        </div>
    </form>
  </body>
```

And then in the controller you should be able to fetch the value

```
   var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.user = {};
    $scope.changed = function(){
      console.log("Changed: "+$scope.myForm.email.$viewValue);
    }
    $scope.keyUp = function(){
      console.log("KeyUp: "+$scope.myForm.email.$viewValue);
    }
});
```

## You can read more [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is as per design ng-change first evaluate the expression(email or text) if its valid it will call the function

Lets take an example of text field.

Therefore if there is anything(any text) in `input[text]` it will be valid and fire the function() but in case of email it is only valid if `input[email]` is valid which required some validation to be done and then it will fire the event.

Same goes to $watch it will evaluate the value applied to it `$scope.$watch("user.email")` in this case user.email which will set only if `input[email]` consist valid value.

`ng-keyup` will call always on keyboard event so it will call `function()` in every code.